# Error Updating Maven Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, pom.xml

I downloaded this project(to convert docs to Pdf as the project name say) https://github.com/yeokm1/docs-to-pdf-converter on github then  I tried to import in Eclipse but something is wrong. I got this error.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I also have errors(I have a red cross on this file) in my pom.xml but this is my first project with maven, I'm not able to detect the problem.         Here the code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>docs-to-pdf-converter</groupId>
    <artifactId>docs-to-pdf-converter</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>args4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to see many other questions with a lot of solutions, but no one worked for me.

1) I tried to delete the .m2 folder : Not Worked

2) Try to make right click on the project and then Maven-Update Project: same error. Not Worked

3)I tried to go to WINDOW-PREFERENCE-MAVEN-INSTALLATION and then I changed Embedded with the folder that contains Maven, in my case C:\Maven Not Worked

4)I tried to go to WINDOW-PREFERENCE-JAVA-INSTALLED JREs where at the begin I just had C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65, then I have read somewhere that I need Jdk 7, so I downloaded and install it but it doesn't work too. So, Now I have these two C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 and C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65

I  also post a picture( I have not enough reputation to post two, in ordert to see also the Path Environment Variable)  about the Environment variable, maybe I don't see something obvious. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7u6T.png)

I'm sorry in advance because it could be a very easy question, but as I said above this is my first project with maven/eclipse and I'm not expert in this field.

Comment: What happens if you try to "mvn compile" from command line?

Comment: I got this: `[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.101 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-16T10:22:57+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: `[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Windows\System32). Please verify you invoked Maven from t
he correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception`

Comment: You need to run it from the project's folder where the pom is located...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this project, and it compiled fine using Eclipse Mars.

It sounds like your Maven installation does not know how to go out to the internet to find artifacts. Could there be a firewall in the way?

Also, in Eclipse go to Window/Preferences/Maven/User settings. Make sure the settings.xml is the same one as used by your external Maven installation (assuming you are using an external Maven engine). For instance, I have set both the global and user config files to C:\development\tools64\apache-maven-3.3.3\conf\settings.xml

I checked my settings.xml, and there is no configuration that points to the maven central repository - Maven 3 must just know where to find it.

On the first compile, you should see lots of info messages saying that Maven is downloading artifacts. The next time you compile, these messages will not appear, as the dependencies are now cached in your local repository.

Comment: I don't think it's because of firewall, I'm in a private workstation, I mean I'm working at home. 

I have not settings.xml. , in Window/Preferences/Maven/User settings the path is `C:\Users\My User\.m2\settings.xml` but in the folder is not present that file. In fact If I click on that path , it disappear. While global setting is empty and the Local repository is like `C:\Users\My User\.m2\repository`

Comment: I would install Maven 3, put mvn.exe on your path, then run mvn clean install from the directory that has the .pom file. If that works, the problem is Eclipse setup. If not, then the problem is Internet connectivity. Good luck.